# ¿Como detectar si han pasado x cantidad de segundos en una actividad?

Tags: android

Tengo un cardView que contiene un ImageView y tengo varias imagines. En la configuracion de mi apk puse una opcion de que las fotos pasen automaticamente cada cierta cantidad de tiempo. El problema es que cuando retorno de la configuracion no se actualiza el tiempo. Como le puedo decir a mi actividad que tiene que cambiar el intervalo cuando lo cambie yo en configuracion?

Este es el codigo en el mainActivity

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        currentImage = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        currentImage++;
        if (currentImage > 5)
            currentImage = 0;
        setPictureCard();
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        LoadNextTimeOrCheckCurrent();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }
}


private void LoadNextTimeOrCheckCurrent()
{
    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("checked", false)) {
        // Actualizar cantidad de items
        String integer = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("time_photos", "30");

        boolean minOrSec; // 0 min , 1 sec

        if (integer.indexOf(" ") == 2) {
            if (integer.substring(3, 4).contains("s"))
                minOrSec = true;
            else
                minOrSec = false;

            integer = integer.substring(0, 2);
        }
        else {
            if(integer.length() == 1) {
                integer = integer.substring(0, 1);
                minOrSec = true;
            }
            else if (integer.substring(2, 3).contains("m"))
                minOrSec = false;
            else
                minOrSec = true;

            integer = integer.substring(0, 1);
        }

        if(minOrSec)
            startTime = Integer.parseInt(integer) * 1000;
        else
            startTime = Integer.parseInt(integer) * 60 * 1000;
        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        countDownTimer.start();

    }
}

private void setPictureCard() {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> El problema es que cuando retorno de la configuracion no se actualiza
>   el tiempo

Veo que estás utilizando una Shared Preference para obtener el intervalo guardado ya que en tu código tienes esto:

```
String integer = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("time_photos", "30");
```

En caso de **usar** un layout de preferencias (un .xml con PreferenceScreen) comprueba que tienes el `key` correcto asignado. El campo donde configuras tu intervalo deberá tener un aspecto como este:

```
android:key="time_photos"
```

En caso de **no usar** un layout de preferencias cuando configuras tu intervalo debes guardarlo en las shared preferences tal cual:

```
SharedPreferences preferencias = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferencias.edit();
editor.putString("time_photos", intervalo);
editor.apply();
```

En caso de que lo tengas así, parecido y siga sin devolverte nada te recomiendo que debuguees y compruebes que está entrando por el flujo correcto. Mira también que te está devolviendo la obtención de la shared preference.

---

### EDIT

> haber mira el si me devuelve resultados, lo que qiero es que se
>   actualice en el momento que que cambio el tiempo en la configuracion
>   me entiendes. por ejmplo puse 10 segundos y antes estaba en 30 que
>   cuando vaya atras no se demore 30 en cambiar la foto para despues
>   actualizar a 10 me entiendes?

El problema entonces es otro distinto. No se te actualiza porque el método `LoadNextTimeOrCheckCurrent()` que usas para comprobar si has actualizado la configuración lo tienes en el `onfinish()` del countdowntimer. Es decir, que lo **comprobará una vez termmine la cuenta atrás**.

Para solucionarlo es tan sencillo como llamar al `countDownTimer.onfinish()` una vez **regreses de tu configuración**. Si usas una segunda actividad para manejar la configuración, esto puedes incorporarlo en el método `onStart()`/`onResume()` (prueba con uno u otro ya que no se el flujo de tu aplicación). Si por el contrario usas fragments incorporalo en el    `onAttach()`.

Comment: Al que se ha dedicado a restar puntuación a mis últimas repuestas, lo mínimo si puntúas negativamente es comentar el motivo, o al menos plantear una solución alternativa ;)

Comment: haber mira el si me devuelve resultados, lo que qiero es que se actualice en el momento que que cambio el tiempo en la configuracion me entiendes. por ejmplo puse 10 segundos y antes estaba en 30 que cuando vaya atras no se demore 30 en cambiar la foto para despues actualizar a 10 me entiendes?

Comment: he editado la respuesta incoporando lo que dices. Mira a ver si te sirve

Comment: me parece una gran idea gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo poner como contenedor un elemento llamado `ViewFliper` como elemento padre de tus imágenes, el cual va controlar que tus imágenes pasen una tras otra tipo carrusel. Entonces en tu `CardView` cambia `ImageView` por `ViewFlipper` de la siguiente manera:

```
<ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_inicio"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/flipper_a"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_slidera"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            </ViewFlipper>
```

Las imagenes dentro de `ViewFlipper` son las que van a ir pasando una tras otra cada cierto tiempo, ahora en tu archivo java escribe lo siguiente:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewFlipper viewFlipper = v.findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
        //SE ASIGNA DA LA VELOCIDAD CON LA QUE VAN A IR PASANDO LAS IMAGENES
        viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(2000);
        //Esto es opciónal es una animacion de entrada y salia de las imagenes
        viewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
        viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
        viewFlipper.startFlipping();
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero no es lo que busco mira ya lo actualice y utilizo un viewPager para pasar las fotos

Comment: espero que aun me puedas ayudar